# What is purpose of "Refresh Token Rolling"?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, refresh-token

I now setting up my auth server with `Openiddict` framework and in configuration section I see this:
[image]

What is purpose of refresh token rolling? All I understood until now is that because of this "rolling" my 14 days token expiration time is set up to 30 seconds and I have no idea why I need two versions of expiration time for refresh token.

Comment: Well. According to https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics-16#section-4.13.2 I assume this is just some best practice. Every password flow request server returns for your access and refresh token. After you use refresh token to update access token it returns for you new refresh token as well and the previous one is invalidated after it in 30 seconds. I am not sure in it but it seems to be more secure.

Answer (score 1):

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics-16#section-4.13.2

> - *Refresh token rotation:* the authorization server issues a new
>   refresh token with every access token refresh response.  The
>   previous refresh token is invalidated but information about the
>   relationship is retained by the authorization server.  If a
>   refresh token is compromised and subsequently used by both the
>   attacker and the legitimate client, one of them will present an
>   invalidated refresh token, which will inform the authorization
>   server of the breach.  The authorization server cannot determine
>   which party submitted the invalid refresh token, but it will
>   revoke the active refresh token.  This stops the attack at the
>   cost of forcing the legitimate client to obtain a fresh
>   authorization grant."